# Problemas con Gulp Watch en Linux

Tags: javascript, gulp

Tengo un inconveniente con **Gulp watch** bastante particular. Estoy trabajando sobre **Linux** y estoy usando **Browser-Sync** con Gulp, mi intención es que cuando modifique algún archivo de mi proyecto me recargue el navegador y los dispositivos que tenga visualizando automáticamente. Esto ya lo había hecho pero trabajaba en **Windows**.

La instrucción es simple:

```
return watch('./**/*.*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

Esto en Windows funciona perfecto pero en Linux no. Lo que encontré es que no me recibe ni el . ni el / al inicio de la cadena. Si coloco solamente `*.*` funciona bien, pero obviamente así no me sirve.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionar este inconveniente?

Gracias

Comment: Amigo no utilices el return, hazlo tal cual como dice la documentacion, ejecuta esa linea dentro de una funcion (task)  y veras

Comment: Esa expresión  no te debería dar problemas ya que gulp usa [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#windows) y en este *sólo* se usan *forward-slashes* `/` independientemente del sistema operativo. Creo que debes probar con `'/**/*.*'` a ver si coincide con tus ficheros

Answer (score 0):

Yo hice un proyecto en Github sobre Gulp tal vez te pueda ayudar a resolver tu duda.
Lo encontraras en Gulpfile.js

https://github.com/luisgagocasas/inicializar-gulp

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tines todos tus archivos (JS, CSS, HTML) en una carpeta **`src`**, una simple tarea Gulp con browser-sync se vería así:

```
const gulp   = require('gulp');
const bs     = require('browser-sync').create();
const reload = bs.reload;

gulp.task('watch', function() {

  bs.init({
    server: ['src']
  });

  gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', [reload]);
});
```

La cadena `'src/**/*.*'` pasada a `gulp.watch` en el primer argumento es un patron `glob`, que denota que cualquier archivo (`*.*`) and la carpeta `src/` y cualquier sub directorio en src (`/**/`) debe ser incluido.

Muy en el fondo, GulpJS usa el paquete node [**`glob`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) que soporta Linux al igual que Windows, así que el patron **`src/**/*.*`** es compatible con ambos entornos.